# Find road network lines that don't intersect

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, network, road

in ArcGIS,am looking for a quick way to show the roads that don't intersect [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Select by Location tool. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm

find features that don't intersect (by select features that do intersect, then grab all features not selected)

Since you are working with one layer try using the [Intersect Analysis Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/)

Comment: Thinks, But i have one layer and i can not select the same layer for the target and source layer.

Comment: I updated answer

Comment: I try it , thinks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find isolated road segments, such as an "island" disconnected from the rest of network, you can use a single-source shortest path algorithm to find the distance of all network nodes to any given node on the main network. In ArcGIS, this can be done using the [service area](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) operation in Network Analyst, by using a large cut-off distance/time.

The isolated road segments will be outside of the service area. This works for the more general case when a small number of isolated segments are connected to each other but not to the main road network.